# How to pass value for django forms.SplitDateTimeField?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I'm trying to pass value for django form's [`SplitDateTime`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#splitdatetimefield) field. But it keeps showing me `This field is required` error.

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> class F(forms.Form):
...     a = forms.SplitDateTimeField()
... 
>>> f = F(data={'a': ['2020-04-04', '12:12']})
>>> f.is_valid()
False
>>> f.errors
{'a': ['This field is required.']}
```

where as upon passing the same value to `clean` method of `SplitDateTime` object, it works.

```
>>> b = forms.SplitDateTimeField()
>>> b.clean(['2020-04-04', '12:12'])
datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 4, 12, 12, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>>
```

Is there anyway to overcome form `field required` error? or Am I missing any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, looking at the generated HTML for the field, Django expects each element separately, as `a_0` and `a_1`. So this would work:

```
>>> f = F(data={'a_0': '2020-04-04', 'a_1': '12:12'})
```

Comment: yep, it works. Unfortunately I don't find any examples on the internet for bounding a form having `SplitDateTime` field.